# What is the difference between “then” and “than”?

Tags: difference

I want to know the difference between “then” and “than”, when i use it and how, because the pronounce is very similar?

Comment: What about looking up the two words in a dictionary? The structures in which these words are used are so different that there should be no problem in seeing the difference. "than" is used in comparisons after a comparative.

Comment: Its all about the context. but generally, then is used in a antecedent-precedent manner. Something like "do A then do B".than on the other hand is comparing 2 things. 'do A than B'. Here its more like its better to do A than to do B(comparison). In the first one its more like things being in an order.

Comment: I'm wondering about the OP's ability to comprehend 'antecedent-precedent' if than & then are giving difficulty ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compare two things, people or situations, you use **than.** For example, *I am taller **than** you.  Your car is more expensive **than** my car. Life is harder in our country **than** in your country.*

The adverb **then** is used in many senses, some of which are as follows:

1- Meaning *at that time*.  ***Then*** is used to refer to a particular time in the past or
   future.  For example: *I am coming to the party. I'll see you **then**. I went to
   the party yesterday. I met many old friends **then***.

2- **Then** also indicates order of events. *I'll read the letter first, **then** I'll give my advice*